# How is the error of the solutions in your residuals incorporated in the error of minimized variables

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have a pretty straight forward question. Given a system of equations

```
x+y=1
x-y=2
x+2y=3
```

Find the values of x and y. A simple minimization problem.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
sol1=1
sol2=2
sol3=3
fun(k):
    a=k[0]+k[1]
    b=k[0]-k[1]
    c=k[0]+2*k[1]
    residual=(a-sol1)**2+(b-sol2)**2+(c-sol3)**2
    return residual
min=minimize(fun,x0=(0,0))
solution=min.x
error=np.diag(min.hess_inv)
>>>
fun: 1.785714285714286
 hess_inv: array([[ 0.21428571, -0.07142857],
       [-0.07142857,  0.10714286]])
      jac: array([-2.98023224e-08,  0.00000000e+00])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 18
      nit: 4
     njev: 6
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([1.85714285, 0.21428571])
```

So solution found  at x=1.8+/-0.21 and y=0.2+/-0.107 with residual of 1.78. Quite straight forward.

But in this scenario, we assumed our solutions that the residuals were calculated against (i.e. sol1,sol2,sol3) had no errors. But what if there are errors associated with them?

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
sol1=1
sol1_error=0.5
sol2=2
sol2_error=1
sol3=3
sol3_error=1.5
fun(k):
    a=k[0]+k[1]
    b=k[0]-k[1]
    c=k[0]+2*k[1]
    residual=(a-sol1)**2+(b-sol2)**2+(c-sol3)**2
    return residual
min=minimize(fun,x0=(0,0))
solution=min.x
error=np.diag(min.hess_inv)
```

How does one incorporate the errors of the 3 solutions into the final error calculation?

Comment: Even though it's over-determined, this is still entirely linear and should not use minimize. Use `lstsq`, which also gets you residuals

Comment: The setup is just an example, what I'm trying to figure out more is how error is propagated through minimization. From my understanding the calculated inverse Hessian is the error for the minimized solution, but how is the error from the values used in the residuals incorporated/propagated through?